# Disable auto-tuning in Windows XP SP3

Tags: windows-xp, networking

in Windows Vista or 7 I could run.

```
netsh interface tcp set global autotuning=disabled
```

but in Windows XP SP3 32 bit this command showing: `command not found`. Is it possible to do it in XP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not. It's only available in Vista and above, since it's a feature (the tuning).